# Where is the .htaccess file location on mac Sierra v 10.12.2?

Tags: macos

Where is the actual location of this .htaccess file. I am in the 'Show Hidden files' mode but still cannot see this file on my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. Are you sure that file exists in your computer ? .htaccess is not found in macOS by default. To show hidden files in macOS you need to restart Finder after you enabled to show hidden files - otherwise it has no effect..

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
killall Finder
```

.htaccess should be at the root of your web server.

Comment: I have run these two command but still cannot see the .htaccess file in my home directory or web server root directory

Comment: Try FileZilla, it's a popular FTP client for Mac. It has an option in the menubar: Server > Force showing hidden files. If Filezilla not showing you the .htaccess file then I'm pretty sure it's not exist.

Comment: Thanks. So if it's not there then what is the procedure for getting it ?

Comment: Open a text editor like TextEdit, write/paste what you have to put in your htaccess file. Save the file, name it “.htaccess”. A dialogue box will popup saying that “Names that begin with a dot are reserved for the system.” That’s fine, go ahead and click OK to use the dot.